# On the convergence in probability of a sequence of random variables.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\{X_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $E[X_t] = \theta E[X_{t-1}]$ for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$ where $|\theta|< 1$ and $E[X_0] = \mu > 0$.

Then does the sequence $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ given by

$$Y_t = \frac{X_t X_{t-1} + X_{t-1}X_{t-2} + \dots X_1 X_0 }{X_t^2+X_{t-1}^2+ \dots + X_{0}^2}$$

Converge in probability to $\theta$ ?

If one is curious as to where this sequence comes from it arises when one minimizes the quantity
$$\sum_{
i = 0}^n ( X_{i+1} - \beta X_i )^2$$ wrt $\beta$. Hopefully this should even give some intuition as to why one could conjecture that the sequence $\{Y_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to $\theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. The condition on the mean does not imply a decay condition on the second moment.

For instance, the Gaussian random variables $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta^t, 1)$ for some $0 < \theta < 1$ satisfy $E[X_t] = \theta E[X_{t-1}]$, but $E[X_t^2]= 1 + \theta^{2t} \geq 1$. In general, the numerator of $Y_t$ behaves like
$$ E\left[\sum_{i=0}^t X_i X_{i-1}\right] \sim (E[X_0])^2 \sum_{i=0}^t \theta^{2i-1},$$
which is bounded as $t \rightarrow \infty$ since $|\theta| < 1$. However, the denominator in this Gaussian case is $O(t)$, so the ratio would converge to $0$ in probability (and a.s.).